# wordpress wont install locally

Tags: wordpress, phpmyadmin, installation, localhost

background: i am using xampp to create a server and run wordpress locally. i assigned the listen server to `8080` as the default 80 was already being used. and the other one (which defaults to 443) to `4433`. i created a dtabase in phpmyadmin `wp_intro` a new user `wp-intro` and set password to none. but it is not working. i have tried-

1. using the default username:root and none password.
2. creating a new user (wp_intro) but it is still stuck on the same thing and wont install.
3. inputting the database connection details directly into `wp-config`

when i omit :8080 from the database host input, it doesnt work at all.

the first image shows the ss after huge amount of time. the second one shows where it's stuck.
i am a front end developer with little to no knowledge of back end so please help me out and dont judge.
[image]

[image: as the image shows the installation wont even begin]

Comment: I think you should try to set and use a database password

Comment: doesn't make a difference @Johannes

Comment: I don't know anything about xampp anymore, but if you're open to trying something new, checkout Local. It just works and it's what I moved to from xampp years ago. https://localwp.com

Comment: The database host **cannot** be on the same port as your webserver (8080). I assume your database server runs on localhost port 3306, you don't need to specify that explicitly unless running it on some port other than 3306.

Answer (score 0):

Your database host is causing the issue, do not enter port and 8080 is the port of your Apache HTTP, not your mysql database which is 3306(default).

1. create the database in phpmyadmin
2. enter the credentials in "wordpress local install" as you created the database
3. if you havent set the database user or password, user is `root` and password is  (nothing)
4. Database host is `localhost` (without port)

Good luck.